# Launch web browser from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have a simple project which is running in a console window. I want to run it in a web browser. How can I achieve it? That means, I want to convert that project into a web browser runnable project. The start button from the Visual Studio tool bar have to change with the web browser name, eg. Firefox. For instance, in an MVC project, in Visual Studio we cant see the Start button, instead of that the browser name is showing. I want to convert my project like that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to switch a console application to an asp.net or an asp.net mvc application.

I think the easiest way is to create a new, empty project of your choice and than to move the code to this project.